# Django gives TypeError at /loadFcs expected string or buffer

Tags: javascript, django, typeerror

In my js I make a simple request as below

```
$.post('/loadFcs', function(data) {alert('hi');});
```

In my urls.py, I have

```
from views import loadFcs
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
  ('^$', direct_to_template, { 'template': 'index.html' }),
  ('^loadFcs$', loadFcs)
 )
```

In my views I have

```
@require_POST
def loadFcs(request):
  results = {}
  //do some calculation and calucalte results, results looks like {"a":["avalue", "bvalue"], "b":["avalue", "bvalue"]}
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results),mimetype="application/json")
```

But I see the following error in my Firebug console under the 'Response' tab

TypeError at /loadFcs
expected string or buffer

Request Method: POST

Where am I making a mistake? I also tried just

```
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
```

but did not work either.

Comment: Never mind, the problem is in the //do some calculation part. I will post more details later

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511725/django-no-text-in-response