# Django no text in response

Tags: django, request, synchronous

somewhere in my views.py,I have

```
def loadFcs(request):
  r = requests.get('a url')
  res = json.loads(r.text)
  #Do other stuff
  return HttpResponse('some response')
```

Now when I call this from my javascript, loadFcs gets called, and *probably* requests.get gets called asynchronously. So I end up seeing ' TypeError at /loadFcs expected string or buffer' and the trace points to the line with

```
res = json.loads(r.text)
```

I also modified my code to check whats the problem, and

```
def loadFcs(request):
  r = requests.get('a url')
  res = json.loads(r.text)
  if r == None:
    print 'r is none'
  if r.text == None:
    print 'text is  None'
  #Do other stuff
  return HttpResponse('some response')
```

and noticed that 'text is none'. So I think I need to adjust code so that request.get is synchronous. I think  the method execution continues and the return statement is hit even before r.text has some value.
Suggestions?

Comment: Did you try dumping `r` to see what you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197854/python-requests-fetching-the-head-of-the-response-content-without-consuming-it

Comment: @romainberger what do you mean by dumping? I am already checking if r.text is NONE or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so I tried the same thing with python command line and it worked BUT not with the same code in my server.
So what was the problem?

apparently, response.text is in some encoding ( UTF8) which my server was not set to receive, so it was just throwing it away and hence null.

Solution: use response.content ( which is raw binary)